# Issues in vertical hr line in html and css

Tags: html, css

I have been created the web page using html and css.

I have been created two products in one column.

I need to add vertical hr line between these two products.

For that i did,

Html:

```
<div class="headerDivider"></div>
```

Css:

```
.headerDivider {
     border-right:1px solid #16222c; 
     height:400px;
     margin-right: 458px;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

It doesn't work correctly, Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22z6vjrx/

Can anyone please help me to fix this,

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: Could you simplify the the code and just show us the issue? there is really a lot of CSS. And what is exactly the issue? I see a border on the right.

Comment: be more specific, +3000 lines of css for just one thing won't help. and what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: but your problem is not the vertical lign, but that the products are next to each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to float all of divs (or inline-block display). But I prefer to add vertical line as border on right for elements:

```css
.product {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.first {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.product:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.second {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.third {
  background-color: #dfd;
}
.fourth {
  background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='clear'></div>
  <div class="product first"></div>
  <div class="product second"></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='clear'></div>
  <div class="product third"></div>
  <div class="product fourth"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Updated version**
Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include border and padding to element width (otherwise with will be too big as it will be `width` + `border-width` * 2 + `padding` * 2). Also make sure you have floated products divs as well as vertical hr:

```css
.product,
.vhr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.product {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.first {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.second {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.vhr {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product first"></div>
<div class="vhr"></div>
<div class="product second"></div>
```

Comment: We're not coding for you. Remove your `<div class="headerDivider"></div>` and try it the way @Justinas explained and then ask again when it's still not working ;)

Comment: I need like this, http://s17.postimg.org/z5bzdcwen/layout.jpg .. and i can't able to change my existing code.

Comment: i have an one doubt,,is it possible to share my web page document by using html,css and jquery? please guide me, i posted new question, but i got downvote only..

Comment: @chinna You mean share source code or just place everything in server and in that way ppl will be able to see contents

Comment: @Justinas:  I mean, need like this link http://www.gatesnotes.com/Development/Omniprocessor-From-Poop-to-Potable and ,, here is tha image.. http://s21.postimg.org/vwdgecb1z/Untitled_1.png

Comment: @chinna Use API / SDK for that, e.g. facebook SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs